# Handler for Sum using one TextField in Calculator

Tags: java, handler

I'm trying to create a handler that can add two numbers from one textfield (JTextField) In the code below I have a handler that uses two textfields. It's for a little calculator program.

Could you be so nice to explain it to me in detail because i'm new to Java.

```
class somKnopHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        String inVoer1 = invoer1.getText();
        double invoer1 = Double.parseDouble ( inVoer1 );

        String inVoer2 = invoer2.getText();
        double invoer2 = Double.parseDouble ( inVoer2 );

        Double resultaat = (invoer1 + invoer2 );
        uitvoer.setText( String.format( "%.2f", resultaat));
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on which parts are not clear. Either you wrote something yourself and have no idea what it does, or you copied it from some kind of a tutorial that should answer all your questions...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know what the code above is doing, i'm asking for help to make new code that can add two numbers which come from one textfield.